# Is there any way to access Dynasty Traits in offline mode?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

I am playing Might and Magic Heroes VI and have come across Dynasty Traits.  It appears that they are not available when playing in offline mode.  Is there any way to enable them while in offline mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think so. It's a feature reserved for online so that you can't have it if you crack the game. It's ubisoft baby.

Answer (score 1):

No. Dynasty is part of the Conflux, and it is not available when offline, in the same way that dynasty weapons, heroes and savegames. They are only available when you are connected to your Uplay account.